# Scroll with arrow keys while text input is focused (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll, keyboard, focus

I want to scroll a HTML page with the arrow keys while a text input is focused. The focus on the input field is created with this code:

```
document.getElementById('search').focus();
```

I have to keep the input field active, because I have a barcode scanner which writes into this field.

Is it possible with Javascript to have the input text field active and allow scrolling with the arrow keys at the same time?

I use IE 6 on a Windows CE 6.0 based mobile scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not - you can simply add an event handler to a keys and scroll using jquery.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
       // get current scroll
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

       $(window).scrollTop(scroll+10);
       return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        // get current scroll
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

       $(window).scrollTop(scroll-10);
       return false;
    }
});
```

Where

```
37 - left
38 - up
39 - right
40 - down
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a trick question, you have to disable autocomplete on the input :

```
<input id="search" autocomplete="off" />
```

then bind the event handler etc :

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    // normalize event.which
    if ( event.which == null && (event.charCode != null || event.keyCode != null) ) {
        event.which = event.charCode != null ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
    }

    if ( document.activeElement.id === 'search' ) { // #search has focus
        if (event.which === 38) { // up arrow
            window.scrollBy(0, -50);
        }else if (event.which === 40) { // down arrow
            window.scrollBy(0, 50);
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('search').focus();
```

Note that when the body has focus, the arrows keys will as default scroll the page, so to test the function you have to focus something other than the body

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VN3kS/1/)